# Replace string in XML from bash without writing regex

Tags: xml, string, bash, replace, xml-parsing

I have a large flat file containing many instances of a repeated string I would like to remove:

```
<content type="html">
  &lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;p&gt;Jump around on couch, meow constantly until given food.&lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;
</summary>
```

Because [you can't parse [X]HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/712334) I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to write my own regex. I tried using `tr` without any luck. Here's my desired output:

```
<content type="xhtml">

  &lt;p&gt;Jump around on couch, meow constantly until given food.&lt;/p&gt;

</summary>
```

How can I remove the repeating string from bash without writing regex?

Comment: since it is xml, look into https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xmlstarlet/info.. I haven't used it personally, so I don't how it can be used for this case...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used a tool called [`rpl`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files) which didn't require me to write any regex:

```
$ rpl '&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;' '' /tmp/file

Really DELETE all occurences of &lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt; (case sensitive)? (Y/[N]) Y
Replacing "&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;" with "" (case sensitive) (partial words matched)
A Total of 55 matches replaced in 1 file searched.
```

Installed via Homebrew with `brew install rpl`. Finished in 2 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

With the knowledge of regular expressions it would be:

```
sed -i.bck 's~&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;~~g' /tmp/file
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution. I've updated the question to try and make it more clear what I'm trying to achieve and why RegExp may not be the best approach for my needs.